# Sending email from webpage using Outlook

Tags: vbscript, outlook, outlook-2007

I have a webpage that has a button that sends a letter on the page to an email recipent. Currently we are use Lotus Notes and with VB script, we are able to create an object of Lotus Notes and one of the properties for this object is PutInFolder.  After the user clicks on the email button, the script will send the email and also put save the email in a certain folder on the user's computer.  Our company is now switching over to Outlook 2007 and I'm looking to do the same thing with an Outlook object instead.  Our development is local intranet only, and there are only a few users that will have access to this.  Anyway, my problem is I cannot seem to find the same functionality with an Outlook Application.

I do have the send of the email currently working using this logic.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to save the email in the user's outlook folder?  I tried looking for a list of properties that I can call but I cannot find anything searching. Maybe I don't have the right terminalogy in the searches.

Thank you.

```
sub send_mailvb(sendto, sendcc, sendbcc, subject_text, body_text, attachment1, attachment2, attachment3)

'Open mail, adress, attach report
dim objOutlk    'Outlook
dim objMail 'Email item
dim strMsg
const olMailItem = 0
'Create a new message
    set objOutlk = createobject("Outlook.Application")
    set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem)

' Setup send to
    objMail.To = sendto

' Setup send cc
If sendcc <> "" Then
objMail.cc = sendcc
End If

' Setup send bcc
If sendbcc <> "" Then
objMail.bcc = sendbcc
End If

'Set up Subject Line
    objMail.subject = subject_text

'Add the body

    strMsg = body_text & vbcrlf

'Add an attachments
If attachment1 <> "" Then
    objMail.attachments.add(attachment1)
End If

If attachment2 <> "" Then
    objMail.attachments.add(attachment2)
End If

If attachment3 <> "" Then
    objMail.attachments.add(attachment3)
End If

    objMail.body = strMsg
    objMail.display 'Use this to display before sending, otherwise call objMail.Send to send without reviewing

'Clean up
set objMail = nothing
set objOutlk = nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference... I found the solution I was looking for.  It wasn't too bad of a mess.  Here's the modified source to replicate the Send and save email to a specific folder incase someone else comes looking. Thanks to Tester101 for the website I was looking for.   Again this is vbscript imbedded in the HTML page.

```
    sub send_mailvb(sendto, sendcc, sendbcc, subject_text, body_text, attachment1, attachment2, attachment3)

    'Open mail, adress, attach report  

    dim objOutlk    'Outlook
    dim objMail 'Email item
    dim strMsg
    dim myInbox
    const olMailItem = 0
    'Create a new message
        set objOutlk = createobject("Outlook.Application")
        Set objNameSpace = objOutlk.Session 
        set objMail = objOutlk.createitem(olMailItem)

        Set myNameSpace = objOutlk.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set myExplorer = objOutlk.ActiveExplorer


    ' 6 at least on my machine pointed to the Inbox (should be the same as constant olFolderInbox).  Within the Inbox I have a folder called Test
    Set myExplorer.CurrentFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("Test")
    Set myFolder = myExplorer.CurrentFolder

    ' Setup send to
        objMail.To = sendto

    ' Setup send cc
    If sendcc  "" Then
    objMail.cc = sendcc
    End If

    ' Setup send bcc
    If sendbcc  "" Then
    objMail.bcc = sendbcc
    End If

    'Set up Subject Line
        objMail.subject = subject_text

    'Add the body

        strMsg = body_text & vbcrlf

    'Add an attachments
    If attachment1  "" Then
        objMail.attachments.add(attachment1)
    End If

    If attachment2  "" Then
        objMail.attachments.add(attachment2)
    End If

    If attachment3  "" Then
        objMail.attachments.add(attachment3)
    End If

        objMail.body = strMsg
        // objMail.display 'Use this to display before sending, otherwise call objMail.Send to send without reviewing


        objMail.Save
        objMail.Move(myFolder)

        objMail.Send

    'Clean up
    set objMail = nothing
    set objOutlk = nothing

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this article. It might be something tha could help.

http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail_print.aspx?id=1041

If not this site has great resources for working with outlook.

Comment: -1: Outlook **doesn't work** from ASP.NET or any other server application.

Comment: Where does he mention anything about server application or asp.net? What's up with the negative about something that doesn't even apply to this question.

He says local intranet using vb.

Comment: @spinon: good catch. I've removed the downvote and will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I tried the example above but it didn't like the Dim NS as NameSpace in the imbedded html vbscript. I don't remember the exact error.  I suppose I should have shown how my script tag looked. 
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
' code here.
</SCRIPT>

Comment: An alternative that I thought of, is to send a copy of email to the user by putting the user in the BCC, then creating a rule in the user's outlook to move the email after they receive in their inbox.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the MailItem object has a [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175280(v=office.12).aspx) method, as well as a [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175283(v=office.12).aspx) method. So you should be able to do something like this.

```
objMail.SaveAs "C:\Test.msg", 3
```

The 3 is to save the message in olMSG format see [OlSaveAsType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208132(office.12).aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not certain if they want save to the pc. However maybe to the network. But it has to be by user. We'll see.

Comment: Actually, it was to save to a folder in outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. We've decided to bcc the person sending the email and then use an outlook rule to move the email to the specified outlook folder. Thanks to everyone that replied.